# UFT does not recognize webfile object

Tags: hp-uft

**Application:**

[image]

**Recorded step:**

```
Browser("DocumentIndex_2").Page("DocumentIndex").WebFile("files[]").Set "kk"
```

**Object Repo:**

[image]

Run time error:

> Error Details Run Error - Step Cannot identify the object "files[]"
>   (of class WebFile). Verify that this object's properties match an
>   object currently displayed in your application. Description Cannot
>   identify the object "files[]" (of class WebFile). Verify that this
>   object's properties match an object currently displayed in your
>   application.
>
> Object's physical description: miccommentproperty =  Mercury Class =
>   WebFile Html Tag = INPUT
>   _xpath = //DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/SPAN[normalize-space()="Select files"]/INPUT[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRA1O.png) |Visible = -1 Type = file Name = files[] Html Id = 
>   DHTML Class =

In Object Repository, I was able to highlight the object. I am not sure why UFT would not click the object during run time. How can I instruct UFT to click the object?

Comment: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib~WebFile.html

The code looks okay. According to the official doc it is not supported in Chrome and PhantomJS. What browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome 70. It clicks other objects in chrome. I am having problem with this one.

Comment: @BelaTamasJozsa actually I think it is supported on Chrome, just not when Chrome is in emulation mode, quote: _This object is not supported on browsers running on a Mobile device connected to Mobile Center or Chrome emulator browsers, or PhantomJS_

Comment: Right only Chrome Emulator Browsers. if we wanna be picky, theoretically UFT does not support version 70 yet - although practically there are no huge differences, so let's just ignore... still for the sake of completeness can you please try it in iexplore / firefox?

Comment: I just checked and it worked for me on Chrome70, from the error it looks like UFT couldn't recognise the file object. Try disabling automatic XPath identifiers (Tools->Options->GUI Testing->Web->Advanced-> Uncheck "Lean and run using automatic XPath identifiers"

Comment: This object is visible upon loading the jquery. I talked to micro focus. They said UFT does not support identifying the object which is visible only by loading jquery.